# Processing a huge vector grid creation on QGIS with square grid size of 100m x 100m

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

As a complete beginner to the world of GIS, I have come across a major roadblock:

My goal is to create a grid with 100m * 100m square grid boxes over the total area of Canada and USA. I have managed to locate a source file with GeoJSON data of Canada and USA however when using QGIS 3.28 LTR whenever I try to generate the grid QGIS crashes the entire system.

I have even tried running QGIS on topend AWS Workplace with 8 vCPUs and 32gb of RAM however QGIS keeps crashing. I thought of generating the grid separately for Canada and USA however in that case I would run into overlapping grids which would be very hard to filter out.

How can I go about accomplishing this task?

Comment: That's roughly 2 million cells. Those don't come for free...neither in creating, nor handling in whatever later analysis you're trying to run on them. One of the foremost advantages of regular grids is that you can *round coordinates to their bounds* very cheaply - maybe you do not need to create a grid explicitly to do your work?

Comment: @geozelot 
 I do understand your point however at this point I am planning to show this grids as plots over the map that user can purchase and own a property virtually. I have figured and coded most of the stuff the only missing piece of the puzzle is the data.  I am estimating around 2 billion cells of Data as my previous experiment of USA only with 2km * 2km area resulted in 11 million cells. I just want to know what kind of processing power do I need to get this amount of data generated or if there any better ways to get this done.

Comment: Two gigacells at 40-100 bytes per cell is *way* larger than the RAM you have allocated. There's a reason GIS professionals don't do it this way.  It seems you have more than one piece missing here.

Comment: WhatCRS do you use?

Comment: I think that you do not really need a physical grid. You could create x and y indexes and  plot number 200000/459000 can be located just like we use coordinates `45.77868/-108.58019` in https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/45.77868/-108.58019. Then you need a function that creates the gridlines on-the-fly when the map is used at reasonable scale. I do not know how to program it but I believe that an Index grid example in https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/java/e218806a-35f5-48d4-a09a-81c2319729d8.htm is doing something like that.

Comment: If you just want to display a grid you can go to: View- Decorations - Grid

Comment: @Babel OGC:CRS84 in Qgis

Comment: @vince how would you go about this considering it is a web project that uses PHP as backend. I don't need specifics just point me towards some possible approach and I will try it out.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks, I will check it out and let you know.